# Упрощение и автоматизация поиска товаров по смете для заказа в разных магазинах

Tags: алгоритм, парсер, автоматизация

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно упростить следующую задачу:**
Составляется смета с названиями товаров в excel файле, их может быть например 50 штук и надо их найти и заказать в разных магазинах, в зависимости от того что где есть и какие цены. Вручную копипастить в поиск по сайтам неудобно, да еще на несколько магазинов сразу, открывая кучу страниц в браузере - хотелось бы максимально упростить этот поиск и заказы.

**Как я вижу решение:**
Например на php, импортировать товары из excel и формировать ссылку поискового запроса для каждого магазина, открывая каждую такую ссылку во фреймах, что бы открывались все магазины на одной странице и не приходилось открывать множество вкладок и переключаться между ними и все было перед глазами.
Потом из выпадающего списка выбирать следующий товар, импортированный из сметы, что приведет к обновлению фреймов.

Если возникнут идеи, подскажите пожалуйста более полезный вариант по упрощению данной задачи, или же готовое решение.

Comment: у вас конкретный список магазинов? У каждого из магазинов есть поисковая ссылка? Как вы это поддерживать будете для новых магазинов? Вы собираетесь открыть фреймы на все магазины на одной странице? У этих магазинов есть какое то АПИ?

Comment: @tym32167 конкретный список магазинов для заказов. Поисковые ссылки выглядят примерно таким образом */search/?q=товар Для многих магазинов полагаю поисковые запросы подобным образом выглядят. Фреймы на все магазины на одной странице собираюсь открыть, но не на все товары, иначе может быть более 100 фреймов и это мне кажется не очень удобно, поэтому поочередно выбирать товар из списка и производить поиск одновременно в нескольких магазинах, которых не так много, обычно в 2-3 самых крупных находятся все товары, редко в 5-7 приходится искать. У магазинов вряд ли есть API да и зачем оно магазинам?

Comment: Мне кажется, вам будет полезно взять ручку, бумажку и нарисовать то, что вы хотите реализовать. Прямо интерфейс, который у вас получится. Там и поймете, удобно это или нет.

Comment: @tym32167 да, я лишь подумал, может быть мне какая то простая мысль/идея в голову не пришла, но глядя на мой вопрос, может быть кто то подсказал бы как это сделать еще проще и удобнее. Или даже готовое решение для подобных задач существует.

Comment: ну тут много переменных. Например, можно сделать навороченную автоматизированную систему, которая все сама делать будет - то её надо поддерживать. Или можно попробовать договориться с магазинами за некоторую денюшку выкачивать все их товары с ценами раз в день (раз у вас строгий список магазинов) в каком нить csv формате и парсить. Тут нужен какой то анализ, что ли. Можно вообще написать простую HTML страничку с jquey куда в поле вставляется имя товара и страничка откроет все магазины во фреймах - тут даже сервер не нужен.

Comment: Может с магазинами поговорить, как они это видят, им ведь должно быть выгодно.

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov магазин в котором чаще всего заказы делаются, не заморачивается и всегда отправляет в личный кабинет, что бы через него делались заказы и для автоматического выставляется счета. В другом магазине можно отправить смету и они сами сведут-сопоставят названия товаров и выпишут счет, но делают это субъективно и часть товаров в их счете окажется не тем что было нужно, поэтому придется перепроверять, да и ждать ответа по смете из 50-100 товаров придется не один день.